# All Kähler threefolds embed into a common complex manifold

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, complex-geometry

Is there a closed complex manifold into which all closed complex threefolds admitting a Kähler structure embed?

Comment: Why would you expect one to exist? Is there such a thing for complex surfaces and threefolds are the next case?